# What is the sole purpose of int and .strip() when creating a variable for simple comprehension?

Tags: python

My objective is to print a dictionary where the keys are the inputted numbers, and the values are the squares of those numbers. For example, if the index is `my_list= 1, 2, 3, 4`, then the script should print `{1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16}`.

An `AttributeError` occurred saying:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

I realized I need to define the list in order for me to split. 
I did some research on how to define the list for simple comprehension and was told `int(.split())` can be helpful. I'm assuming I need to convert the list into integers?

This is what I tried in the beginning:

```
print({num: num ** 2 for num in my_list.split()})
```

Comment: `split` is a method on a `string`, that takes an optional parameter, which turns it into a `list` of elements separated by that parameter; e.g `'wild-goose-chase'.split('-')` becomes `['wild', 'goose', 'chase']`

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over a list directly without split Try this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print({num: num ** 2 for num in my_list})
```

output:

```
{1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16}
```